# Is it possible that I have deleted all of my databases in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

So i dropped by db as you do with the following command:

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

then when i follow up with

```
show dbs
```

only

`local 0.000gb`

comes up.

Bear in mind there must have been at least 20 there previously.  I'm hopeful i can still access them somehow.  Or are they gone forever?

Comment: `db.dropDatabase()` only drops the current database, it does however seems like your databases are gone somehow. So I'd say that your best bet is to just restore a backup, for you have backups, right?

Comment: Oh dear.  This is how we learn.  Thanks for the comment